# Jersey Security Digest vs Basic Auth

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, jersey, digest

Could anyone explain to me why basic auth is working and the digest isn't working or not showing up in the http headers on the server anyway.

```
public String login(UserDTO user)
{
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
        clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
        Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
        //    client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()));
        client.addFilter(new HTTPDigestAuthFilter(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()));
        ClientResponse response = client.resource(url + "user/login").accept("application*json").type("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);

        System.out.println(response.toString());

        return null;
}
```

If I use:

```
client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()));
```

I get an authorization header on the server:

```
USER LOGIN REQUEST
request:uri: /StambomenWebAPI/rest/user/login
method: GET
QueryString: null
Parameters:
Headers:
Name: accept    Value: application*json
Name: content-type  Value: application/json
Name: authorization Value: Basic QXhsOkxvbA==
Name: user-agent    Value: Java/1.7.0_51
Name: host  Value: localhost:8084
Name: connection    Value: keep-alive
USER AND PASS[XXXXX, XXXXX]
```

But when I use

```
 client.addFilter(new HTTPDigestAuthFilter(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()));
```

I do not get an authorization header field ... :s ?

Using jersey with tomcat v7

My regards and thx in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting an authorization header field because of the digest authentication workflow. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication#Example_with_explanation) for more details, but basically:

1. Client makes a request with no `Authorization` header
2. Server responds with a 401 status and a `WWW-Authenticate` header that looks something like:

   ```
   Digest realm="testrealm@host.com",
   qop="auth,auth-int",
   nonce="dcd98b7102dd2f0e8b11d0f600bfb0c093",
   opaque="5ccc069c403ebaf9f0171e9517f40e41"
   ```
3. Client repeats the request with the correct `Authorization` header now that it has digest info from server

From the client side, this is all handled by the Jersey `HTTPDigestAuthFilter`. So, the filter makes the request without an `Authorization` header first, and your server should return a 401 status with a `WWW-Authenticate` header that has the necessary Digest info. Then the filter repeats the request with the correct `Authorization` header, and your server should authenticate and return the content.

After this initial handshake, the `HTTPDigestAuthFilter` remembers the necessary digest info, so for all requests after the very first request, the `Authorization` header will be included.